# How to get data from database instead of resource in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to get data from database instead of string resource.

**Here is my code.** where I want to show the data as a ListView. My ListView is now currently working with a custom list adapter.

```
 import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.rupomkhondaker.sonalibank.adapter.PhoneListAdapter;
import com.rupomkhondaker.sonalibank.model.ContactItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class GMOFragment extends Fragment {
    public GMOFragment(){}

    private ArrayList<ContactItem> phoneItems;
    private PhoneListAdapter adapters;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gmo, container, false);

        final ArrayList<ContactItem> listData = getListData();

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gmolistView);
        listView.setAdapter(new PhoneListAdapter(getActivity(), listData));


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                ContactItem newsData = (ContactItem) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ContactDetail.class);
                intent.putExtra("DATA_KEY", newsData);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

        return rootView;
    }
    private ArrayList<ContactItem> getListData() {

        ArrayList<ContactItem> datalist = new ArrayList<ContactItem>();
        DataBaseHelper dbHelper=new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
        datalist = dbHelper.getAllContacts();

        return datalist;
    }
}
```

**Here is My DataBaseHepler.java this create the database successfully !**

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.rupomkhondaker.sonalibank.model.ContactItem;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String BR_NAME = "BR_NAME";
    private static final String PHONE = "PHONE";
    private static final String MOBILE = "MOBILE";
    private static final String EMAIL = "EMAIL";
    //Set the database path
    public static String DB_PATH;

    //databse string
    public static String DB_NAME;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public final Context context;



    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return database;
    }

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 1);
        this.context = context;

        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
        DB_NAME = databaseName;
        openDataBase();
    }

    //Create Databse
    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }
    //Check DataBase exsist or not
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }
        //Close database
        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }
    //Coping The Data bse
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        //find database from asets assets
        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // File path
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // setfile name
        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // read database
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        return database;
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}

    //Getting the data from database

    public List<ContactItem> getAllContacts()
    {

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select BR_NAME,PHONE,MOBILE,EMAIL from SBL_Contact",null);
        ArrayList<ContactItem> listMockData = null;

        if (cursor .moveToFirst()) {
            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                ContactItem newsData = new ContactItem();

                newsData.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BR_NAME)));
                newsData.setPhone(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PHONE)));
                newsData.setMobile(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MOBILE)));
                newsData.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EMAIL)));
                listMockData.add(newsData);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        return listMockData;
    }
}
```

Please help me to set data into `getListData()`  from my database instead of resource.

Note: My database has same columns like listarray with same data.

Comment: Did you look for any tutorials on how to do it?  There are probably dozens.

Comment: Yes I did but failed to implement :( . can anyone help me with my code ?

Comment: You need to provide details on exactly what problem you're encountering.  Nobody is interested in writing your code for you, but we will help you figure out specific problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DatabaseHelper.java` Add this method

```
public List<ContactItem> getAllContacts()
{
Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from table",null);
ArrayList<ContactItem> listMockData;

if (cursor .moveToFirst()) {

            while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
                ContactItem newsData = new ContactItem();
                newsData.setName(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(name))); /DB Column Name : name
                newsData.setPhone(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(phone));
                newsData.setMobile(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(mobile)));
                newsData.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(email)));
                listMockData.add(newsData);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
         return listMockData;
    }
```

And in your `getListData()`

```
 private ArrayList<ContactItem> getListData() {

     ArrayList<ContactItem> datalist = new ArrayList<ContactItem>();  
     DatabaseHelper dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
     datalist=dbHelper.getAllContacts();

      return datalist;
}
```

Comment: I want to show list in a fragment so `getApplicationContext()` may not work ?

Comment: i've Updated Code,use `getActivity()` for fragment

Comment: Not Works same error red under line. So I have update my question with your given code so you can look into it where I make mistake ?

Comment: how to add a shorting system into my custom listView